# Can I use a gerund after "having"?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

The sentence I'm having trouble with is:

*Show the class how to perform the activity by having one student act as the giver and you acting as the receiver.*

Should it be "you act as the receiver" or "you acting as the receiver"?

Comment: Yes, that one's no problem. There's a strange reluctance to put _-ing_'s too close together in English, but the more irrelevant words you put between them the less anyone notices. This is a corollary of Zwicky's Law.

Comment: I would use the same thing in both:  "one student act" and "you act".  Maybe even better "having one student act" and "having you act".